# Best way to index four fields

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-ce

I have a query like below

> > SELECT vbShape, XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX, AnnotationClassID, Angle, GlobalID, FlipAngle, FlipAngle, Bold, FontName, Italic, Underline, TextString FROM (select * FROM wtrServiceAnEs WHERE XMIN is not null) A WHERE (XMIN <= -13045469.3971009 AND XMAX >= -13047074.5746947 AND YMIN <= 4021390.27603748 AND YMAX >= 4019785.09844372) This results in 1000 rows. the table (wtrServiceAnes) can have anywhere from 100000- 500000 rows

I get huge performance problems based on the way my app works.  I don't have a ton of experience with indexes.  So I am wondering what is the best way to index these four fields in sql server to achieve the best performance?  Should I create one index with multiple fields?  2 indexes for 2 fields each?  One index for each field?  Clustered vs Non-Clustered?  And, no I cannot use a spatial index as my app is using sql compact.  Sorry for my inexperience here.  Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: Can you run your query using SSMS? if so, you should click the "show actual execution plan" button before running it, and see what index (if any) is suggested.

Comment: Sorry but how do I intrepret the results?  The result just shows as "Clustered Index Scan (Clustered)" and then it gives me info about execution time and stuff like that.  How do I know what fields to index?

Comment: If the query optimizer thinks you need to add an index you'll see a green remark on the top starting with the words "missing index". You can right click it and see the details (it opens a create index script in a new script window).

Comment: I don't see a green arrow.  That can't be right.  That indiciates that an index wouldn't help at all

Comment: I didn't say that. Perhaps it wouls be better if you posted the table structure, the query and the execution plan.

Comment: Query is like this   

**SELECT vbShape, XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX, AnnotationClassID, Angle, GlobalID, FlipAngle, FlipAngle, Bold, FontName, Italic, Underline, TextString FROM (select * FROM wtrServiceAnEs WHERE XMIN is not null) A WHERE (XMIN <= -13045469.3971009 AND XMAX >= -13047074.5746947 AND YMIN <= 4021390.27603748 AND YMAX >= 4019785.09844372)**

This results in 1000 rows.  the table (wtrServiceAnes) can have anywhere from 100000- 500000 rows

Comment: No, edit your question.